# After installing the ssl magento checkout is not working?

Tags: php, magento

I have installed ssl in my site .

```
Base URL:  https://sitename.com/

Base Link URL:  https://sitename.com/

Base Skin URL:  https://sitename.com/skin

Base Media URL:  https://sitename.com/media

Base JavaScript URL:  https://sitename.com/js

Use Secure URLs in Frontend:  Yes

Use Secure URLs in Admin:  No
```

I cleared the caches also.

Now checkout is not working.

I am getting **302 Moved Temporarily** in my browser console.

How to fix this?
Can this be because in correct setting in apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of varnish.
Checkout page should not be cached
After clearing varnish caches it worked.